# Is there a have MongoJack work with BSON Date

Tags: java, mongodb, mongojack

By default it looks like mongojack stores DateTime as a long in Mongo.  Is there a simple way to have it store the dates as BSON Date instead?

For example the following ends up as a long in Mongo and I'd want to have a BSON Date

```
@JsonProperty("date") date: DateTime
```

Comment: Can you show me an example ? Is `DateTime` from  joda lib ? Have you tried using `java.util.Date` ?

Comment: Note that the [answer from the orignal poster of the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29403386/2313887) question is actual answer. For some reason the answer that incorrectly tries to render a string "ISODate" was accepted. That is incorrect since it would just be stored as a "string" and not a BSON date.